# Why is my image moving back?

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to move an image across the screen and then interacting with a text field. I programmed a buttton that defines what the position of the image is, randomly. Now, if I try to change the text in the text field, the image automatically moves back to its predetermined place. I want to know why this is happening and how can I fix it.

Comment: It would help if you updated your question with relevant code and better explained what is happening versus what should be happening.

Answer (score 0):

> Now, if I try to change the text in the text field, the image automatically moves back to its predetermined place. I want to know why this is happening and how can I fix it.

It's because when you change the text, *layout* is performed, and so everything is positioned according to the auto layout constraints you have applied to it. You never changed the image view's constraints, so it goes back to where you left those constraints.